# Programmatically generated GridLayout has column being pushed to the right

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, android-xml, android-gridlayout

I am programmatically generating a `GridLayout` of `TextViews`. I want the second and third columns (`TextViews`) of the `GridLayout` to have equal width, and when there is a lot of text in the `TextViews`, I want the `TextViews` to expand vertically downwards instead of occupying more space. I am trying to achieve this by programmatically setting the column weight of the second and third `TextViews` to be 1. However, when there is lot of text in the second `TextView` for instance, the second and third `TextViews` just get pushed to the side. Below is a screenshot:

[image]

However, this is what I want my application to look like:
[image]

Below is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rowCount="1"
    android:columnCount="3">
    <!-- Difference Table -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/difference_table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></LinearLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Below is my Kotlin code:

```
val diffLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.difference_table)
var diffTable: GridLayout = GridLayout(this)

// Set the dimensions of the grid
diffTable.layoutParams =
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

diffTable.columnCount = 3;
diffTable.rowCount = 1;

// Create the three columns and add them to the grid
var lineNumber: TextView = TextView(this)
lineNumber.text = "asdf"
lineNumber.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
lineNumber.gravity = Gravity.LEFT

var currentLine1: TextView = TextView(this)
currentLine1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
currentLine1.text = "asdfasdfasdfadfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf"
lineNumber.gravity = Gravity.LEFT

// 3. Create the TextView representing the current line in Text 2
var currentLine2: TextView = TextView(this)
currentLine2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
currentLine2.text = "asdfasdfasdfadfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf"
lineNumber.gravity = Gravity.LEFT

// TODO: ENABLE LAYOUT WEIGHT FOR API < 21
diffTable.addView(lineNumber, GridLayout.LayoutParams(
    GridLayout.spec(0, GridLayout.CENTER),
    GridLayout.spec(0, GridLayout.CENTER, 0.0f)));

// Add the current line in Text 1 to the table
diffTable.addView(currentLine1, GridLayout.LayoutParams(
    GridLayout.spec(0, GridLayout.CENTER),
    GridLayout.spec(1, GridLayout.CENTER, 1.0f)));

// Add the current line in Text 2 to the table
diffTable.addView(currentLine2, GridLayout.LayoutParams(
    GridLayout.spec(0, GridLayout.CENTER),
    GridLayout.spec(2, GridLayout.CENTER, 1.0f)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) There should be something wrong with flag on extending GridLayouts. 
Your both `View`s inside `GridLayout` should have weight for vertical and horizontal axis. Try to setup this params for your first and second `View`s above.

```
final GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(
            GridLayout.UNDEFINED,GridLayout.FILL,1f),
            GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED,GridLayout.FILL,1f));
```

2) As an alternative and simple solution, you could replace your both `View`s above with single `LinearLayout` container, which could handle weight by it's own. Something like this.

```
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view.line.1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

          <TextView]
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          </TextView>
       </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view.line.2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

          <TextView]
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          </TextView>
       </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried the first solution and it doesn't seem to work :(. Unfortunately your second solution won't be applicable since I am planning on adding multiple TextViews to the second and third columns.

Comment: @AdamLee You could have as many `View`s inside you second and third columns, as you want. Just to place it inside another parent. Check answer above

Comment: And as for the first solution, it should work for sure. Because that is how we are using it. I think you are missing important part in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I modified a bit in your previous code and added the `width = 0`property, which may achieve the display effect you want

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


//        val diffLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.difference_table)
//        val diffTable = findViewById<GridLayout>(R.id.grid_layout);
        var diffTable: GridLayout = GridLayout(this)

// Set the dimensions of the grid
        diffTable.layoutParams =
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

        diffTable.columnCount = 3
        diffTable.rowCount = 1

// Create the three columns and add them to the grid
        var lineNumber: TextView = TextView(this)
        lineNumber.text = "asdf"
        lineNumber.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
        lineNumber.gravity = Gravity.LEFT

        var currentLine1: TextView = TextView(this)
        currentLine1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
        currentLine1.text = "asdfasdfasdfadfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf"
        lineNumber.gravity = Gravity.CENTER

// 3. Create the TextView representing the current line in Text 2
        var currentLine2: TextView = TextView(this)
        currentLine2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))
        currentLine2.text = "asdfasdfasdfadfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf"
        lineNumber.gravity = Gravity.CENTER

        var layoutParams = GridLayout.LayoutParams()
        layoutParams.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(0, GridLayout.FILL)
        layoutParams.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(0, GridLayout.FILL)

// TODO: ENABLE LAYOUT WEIGHT FOR API < 21
        diffTable.addView(lineNumber, layoutParams)

        var layoutParams1 = GridLayout.LayoutParams()
        layoutParams1.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(0, GridLayout.FILL)
        layoutParams1.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(1, GridLayout.FILL, 1f)
        layoutParams1.width = 0

// Add the current line in Text 1 to the table
        diffTable.addView(currentLine1, layoutParams1)

// Add the current line in Text 2 to the tableLEFT


        var layoutParams2 = GridLayout.LayoutParams()
        layoutParams2.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(0, GridLayout.FILL)
        layoutParams2.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(2, GridLayout.FILL, 1f)
        layoutParams2.width = 0

        diffTable.addView(currentLine2, layoutParams2)


        addContentView(diffTable, ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to dynamically set the column width for the views. Finally it will align each view with required amount of space.

```
var diffTable: GridLayout = GridLayout(this)
            diffTable.setAlignmentMode(GridLayout.ALIGN_BOUNDS);
            diffTable.setColumnCount(3);
            diffTable.setRowCount(1);
            TextView lineNumber;
            for (int i = 0; facilities != null && i < facilities.size(); i++) {
                lineNumber = new TextView(getContext());
                lineNumber.setText(facilities.get(i));
                diffTable.addView(lineNumber, i);
                lineNumber.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(rightIc, 0, 0, 0);
                GridLayout.LayoutParams param =new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
                param.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                param.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                param.rightMargin = 5;
                param.topMargin = 5;
                param.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(c);
                param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(r);
                lineNumber.setLayoutParams (param);

}
```

Where `c` stands for 'column index' and `r` stands for row index of GridLayout.

**Note**: The above code may require a bit of change if you want to insert your parameters.